# How do servers handle scripts? Specifically, scripts that run for a while

Tags: php, apache

I have a script that streams files from a server and saves the data gathered, small chunks at a time to prevent memory overflow, on the host server.

Did I mention it is a PHP script?

This is how it works

```
//loop while data exists on the clients server side file.
while (!feof($xml_fp)) {

                   //grab data in proportions of specified chunk
                   //write the the collected chunk locally
                    //if there's an error, exit (improve error handling for final code)


             $result =  fwrite($local_fp, fread($xml_fp, $size), $size);

                   if($result === false){
        echo"<h1> ERROR </h1>";
        exit(); 
                            }

                   else    {
                $progress += $result;
                ob_flush(); 
                flush(); 
                ?>
               //state amount of data downloaded thus far
                <script>
                $('#progress').html(' ');
                $('#progress').append(<?php echo (float)$progress/(1024*1024) ?>);
                </script>
                <?php

             //if all goes well, increase time limit by a second
                set_time_limit(1);

                     }
}//while loop ends here
```

This script runs well locally. I will have to run plenty of tests on a live server with different sized files to make sure there aren't any issues, however the files can be anywhere from 50mb to 200mb large.

Keeping in mind the fread and fwrite functions have significant over head, I am not expecting a download rate of more than 40 kbps and my estimate of average download times thus the duration for which the script is run would be around 10 minutes.

**Question**: Are servers usually configured to call foul when they detect script run times this long? Please note that this isn't a dedicated server, just a run of the mill shared resource therefore I can't initiate the same with wget through execute() calls or the like.

Comment: By default, the php.ini has a lot of checks on it, max post size, max file upload size, memory allotment, script timeouts.  By configuring those properly, you should have more control over how the server handles the script.  Shared hosting could be tricky business as the php.ini is usually locked down. With a VPS you have more control and usually not that much more $.

Comment: Agreed, but my client is looking for a cheap solution. Trying to convince him to make my life easier has been making my life a lot harder ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers above are correct, but some servers (apache, for example) have scripts in place that will terminate long-running php scripts, regardless of the execution_time set in the apache configuration.

I have solved a similar problem (sending email newsletters for hours and hours) by starting a php_cli process from within the php script. If your host supports it, it is a very reliable way of dealing with these kinds of things.

Another, quite nice, method is to spread the load-time over multiple pages. This can be done by setting [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) on your script, and calling its own URL using curl after getting a single chunk, and exiting.

For both methods you will need a similar method to limit the execution time of the single processes: even though both CLI and Apache should support forever-running scripts, I found they will be stopped after some time. Both methods resemble a relay race: run for 100 meters, then pass the work on to the next worker to run, etc.

To see how I did it with the newsletter stuff, the [code is on github](https://github.com/creativedutchmen/email_newsletter_manager/blob/master/lib/class.emailbackgroundprocess.php)

Comment: by the way, before anyone asks: I don't think killing processes is a 'feature' in apache per-se; I just noticed it consistently happening on my project, and others have rapported the same issue. Where it comes from, and where it can be disabled I do not know.

Comment: That is very insightful! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It could be down to this call:

```
//if all goes well, increase time limit by a second
set_time_limit(1);
```

This comment is not correct. This will give the script a second to run starting from when set_time_limit was called. It may be worth increasing this a bit.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. I won't mark this as an answer though because I am hoping to get more feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends how you're running PHP.

Immediately you need to look at [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time), the documentation also states

> Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. See your web server documentation for specific details.

If you're running PHP via fcgi there will also be timeouts you need to adjust there.

**Edit**

Have you considered asking your shared hosting provider?

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I had considered speaking directly to the web server support service but I didn't really know which technical terms I should be inquiring about. Now I have a decent idea. Thanks again.